# Forwarding messages from my Facebook account to my Gmail account

Tags: facebook

How do I forward messages from my Facebook to my Gmail account.

When I go to messages, it opens in my Messenger account.

Answer (score 1):

Forwarding messages to email, now this feature is not available on Facebook (Facebook has disabled this feature).

To get all your messages on email turn on the email notification:

**Settings** -> **Notifications** -> **Email address**: select *All notifications, except one you unsubscribe from*.

By enabling this you will get email for all the activities on Facebook. Anytime you can unsubscribe any notification from email.

Comment: This is the best possible option though the actual messages are not shown in the email, only a link to open Messenger is provided with the notification telling you that you got a new message.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Facebook allows that anymore. A year ago or so Facebook would send notification for messages with a part of message shown in the email but now even though you have email notifications turned on for messages all you get is a link to open the Messenger conversation with the person who sent you the message and for whom you got the email notification.

In the past Facebook apps could read user's inbox which made it possible for third-party services to setup a service that could read your inbox and then send it over to your email inbox but the feature was removed in Graph API 2.4 and no longer available since then and it is quite certain it will stay that way.

Reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31393889/is-there-any-way-to-use-the-facebook-api-for-reading-user-messages

By default Facebook provides no such option, neither does Facebook allows apps to read user's inbox.